# How to center navbar using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have created a navbar but I cannot figure out how to center it on my webpage. Please advise, I have attached the link to the fiddle right at the bottom. Not sure what else to write as stack overflow is wanting me to provide more details before I post this. Hopefully you can answer my question soon!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <navbar>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        </navbar>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
        <p>Test text</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}



/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/delboy1881/725ncud3/1/

Comment: Are you just wanting you nav menu items centered? Because you navbar spans the entire width of the page i.e. is permanently centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do 2 things
1. Change text alignment to `<navbar>`

```
 navbar{
      text-align: center;
    }
```

This will be so the menu is center in your navbar

2.Remove float and add display

```
.topnav a {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
```

We need to remove the float so the they can align, as you are forcing them left.
And by adding the `display: inline-block` the `<a>` tags will respect your assigned padding.

Remember `<a>` tags are inline elments by default, and you can't asign top and bottom values.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
navbar{
  text-align: center;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <navbar>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        </navbar>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
        <p>Test text</p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks all, I have edited the code to this: https://jsfiddle.net/delboy1881/725ncud3/26/  The problem I have now is when I hover over the "previous winners" link only part of the link is highlighted. How do I make it hover the whole link?

Comment: Happy to help you, but remeber to keep 0ne question per thread. If you can make and other question and paste the link here, I can go and help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

https://jsfiddle.net/90m2m0uh/

```
.topnav a {
    /* dont use this */
    /* float:left */
}
```

Please note at "float" css

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you're asking but I think you just want this. Replace .topnav in your css to this

```
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```